# PHP - if echo $_GET['q']; empty add this TEXT

Tags: php

this is my code

```
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "<?php error_reporting(0); echo $_GET['q'];?>";
```

and if `$_GET['q']` is empty, add my text example: `perfume` how i can do this ?

Thank you. I hope i get help this time.

Comment: `amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase` is not a PHP variable. What language is this?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - It looks like the OP is defining a JS variable, since there's a `<?php ... ?>` in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't turn `error_reporting()` off. That's a bad idea since it will be pretty hard for you to debug your code later on if there are other errors/issues.

If you're using a PHP version older than PHP 7, you can use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
<?= isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'perfume' ?>
```

If you're using PHP 7+, you can use the new shorter null coalescing operator (`??`) syntax that does the same:

```
<?= $_GET['q'] ?? 'perfume' ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the strange stuff in front of your PHP code before the equal sign change this

```
<?php error_reporting(0); echo $_GET['q'];?>
```

to

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0); 
echo (empty($_GET['q']) ? 'perfume' : $_GET['q']);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If `$_GET['q']` is set but empty, you can use the empty ternary operator:

```
<?php echo $_GET['q'] ?: 'perfume'; ?>
```

If `$_GET['q']` is not set, you can use the null coalesce operator:

```
<?php echo $_GET['q'] ?? 'perfume'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help